# Impossible to play video in flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to play video in flutter, and when i launch my code i have this problem

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

This my code:

I create a class VideoApp extend statefulwidget.

_controller contain the video

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(VideoApp());

class VideoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoAppState createState() => _VideoAppState();
}

class _VideoAppState extends State<VideoApp> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'http://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _controller.value.initialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried here and it works. You probably have a network problem, check your Internet connection...

Comment: Okay even when i change `VideoPlayerController.network('http://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4')` to `VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/videos/test.mp4")` it's doesn't work for me.

Comment: Check if you have the latest versions of Flutter and plugins, and post the stack trace if it fails.